# What do you call a pan with tall sides and one long handle?

Tags: image-identification

What do you call it? In Russian we call it "сотейник"

[image]

Comment: Does a сотейник have to have a handle?

Comment: @gotube yes, I believe so

Comment: I ask because when I image search for "сотейник" I find several [pans without handles](https://elmir.ua/frying_pans_stewpans/stewpot_rondell_rda-300_grandis.html), but none when I search for "saucepan". A saucepan always has a handle.

Answer (score 1):

A sauce pan.

Amazon has a good sampling [here](https://www.amazon.com/sauce-pan/s?k=sauce%20pan).

Comment: Actually, it's a **saucepan** (one word).

Comment: I've seen both.

Comment: "Saucepan" is definitely much more common. Some people might reserve "sauce pan" for a pan of this shape which is small enough for preparing sauces (especially French-style sauces).